# Stone cech compactification of a zero dimensional topological space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, gn.general-topology

Let $X $ be a zero dimensional topological space, that is, a topological space with a basis of clopen sets. Is there any characterization for the ston cech compactification for such a space?

Comment: Isn’t $\Bbb N$ such a space? The article in Wikipedia mentions the S-Č compactification of $\Bbb N$ specifically.

Comment: What do you mean: a theorem like "if $X$ obeys these properties then a zerodimensional space $Z$  exists with $\beta Z \simeq X$"? without these purported properties mentioning such a $Z$ it self, but properties being "internal to" $X$, a bit like a metrisation theorem: B-N-S mention regular and special kind of bases.